# Facebook Connect : Return URL

Tags: facebook

I configured facebook connect on my app (localhost) and everything works fine. I can log in / logout. The only thing I was not able to do is move the file xd_receiver.htm in a subfolder. Everything works when it's at the root, but if I try to move it in, lets say, the facebook_connect subfolder, I get this error :

The Facebook Connect cross-domain receiver URL (http://127.0.0.1/xd_receiver.htm#...) must have the application's Connect URL (http://127.0.0.1/facebook_connect/) as a prefix. You can configure the Connect URL in the Application Settings Editor.

I've changed the connect URL in my facebook app settings to :
http://127.0.0.1/facebook_connect/

Is that because I'm on my localhost?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's because your code that references xd_receiver still points to the old location. Double check that your code is consistent about its location.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Everything seemed OK but the I didn't see that you can change the parameter "onlogin" in the "fb:login-button" tag.